# How to convert 8 bit unsigned integer in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

I am trying to convert a file string in to  8 bit unsigned integer.

Please help me in the same, I am clueless for the same.

My Sample code:

```
f = open("/adios.wav")

format = WavFile::readFormat(f)

dataChunk = WavFile::readDataChunk(f)

bit = 'C*'

wavs = dataChunk.data.unpack(bit)
```

Comment: This doesn't work? What results do you get? What results did you expect?

Comment: what i need is 8 bit unsigned integer by reading an audio file,        i am using C* for same... but in ruby doc i found that                                                       Integer      |         |
Directive    | Returns | Meaning
-----------------------------------------------------------------
   C         | Integer | 8-bit unsigned (unsigned char)

Comment: http://apidock.com/ruby/String/unpack

Comment: what is output of format.bitPerSample ?

Comment: @Pritesh , its giving 8 as output

Comment: all seems fine,post results you get and you expect

Comment: 08, 88, 102, 137, 139, 125, 141, 167, 177, 147, 124, 153, 168, 136, 107, 127, 149, 126, 87, 89, 122, 118, 92, 104, 139, 145, 124, 124, 150, 156, 139, 137, 158, 161, 135, 117, 123, 125,
103, 90, 104, 113, 102, 95, 110, 123, 123, 130, 145, 149, 145, 146, 145, 133, 120, 120, 127, 129, 124, 124, 132, 129, 116, 114, 120, 127, 133, 137, 138, 136, 131,

Comment: im getting like this numbers..in an array..                           I am calling an api which needs 8 bit unsigned integer...i dont know if this is rite?

Comment: These are exactly the 8-bit unsigned integers in yout WAV file. In ruby there is no such thing as "unsigned" or "8-bit", they are just Fixnum in the range `(0...255)`. But their values are what you are looking for.

Comment: @Priyanka that is correct result you have provided, for ruby String is hust array of 8bit chars, and only when you have evaluated the string, encoding ASCII/UTF-8/etc will be taken in the consideration. Please provide as the result you want to get from.